# Enum.reduce returns a model instead of a number

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

In my model I have this:

```
  # ....
  def total_price(self) do
    Enum.reduce(self.child_items, fn(x, acc) ->
      x.price + acc
    end)
  end
```

It returns a ChildItem instead of a number representing the total price. Why is that and how to fix that?

Comment: Did you want to pass `0` as the second parameter? `Enum.reduce(self.child_items, 0, fn(...) -> ... end)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Enum.reduce` has two versions: [`reduce/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#reduce/2) and [`reduce/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#reduce/3). The one which takes 2 arguments takes first element in your collection as the initial accumulator - in your case the first `ChildItem`.

What you want to do is provide the initial cost `0` as the accumulator yourself:

```
  def total_price(self) do
    Enum.reduce(self.child_items, 0, fn(x, acc) ->
      x.price + acc
    end)
  end
```